# How to add fields to postgis layer loaded in qgis using python

Tags: postgresql, pyqgis, postgis-2.0

I have loaded a layer from Postgis in qgis and I am adding the fields to the layer using the follo code snippet:

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
aLayer = canvas.currentLayer()
field_name = "test"

aLayer.startEditing()
if not field_name in fieldnames:
      res = aLayer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(field_name, QVariant.String)])
aLayer.updateFields()
aLayer.commitChanges()
```

However, it is not adding the field to the layer. What must I do if I want to add the fields to the layer?

Comment: Are you able to add the field manually under the same user credentials?  Also, were are you defining the fieldnames variable

Comment: @artwork21 Yes once i loaded the layer in qgis i can add the fields manullay but when i am adding through code its not adding the fields.

Comment: Your if condition must be evaluating to true, thus it is not hitting the res= statement to create the field.

Comment: @artwork21 No its going inside the loop and executing res but res is printing false.

Comment: When you add the field manually and click 'Save Edits', does the table update in PostgreSQL ('PG')? For tables where QGIS 'guesses' a primary key (PK) that is not the same as the PG PK, the table will not update in PG. I had that problem with no-PK tables created on-the-fly to check <200 features visually (a PK adds no performance in PG with so few features): when perusing the output I would think *"GAH, I should have added a 'comment_text' column"* and would add a field in QGIS. Although the new field *looked* as if it was added, it didn't change the PG table. I auto-add PKs now...